# Hyper-v ERROR - Video remoting was disconnected unexpectedly

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, ubuntu-18.04, windows-10-1809

I have enabled Hyper-V on my Windows 10 Pro (v.1809) and installed Ubuntu-v18.04.2-64bit Desktop image. In Hyper-V Manager, I have been getting this error when connecting to the virtual machine:

[image: Video remoting was disconnected unexpectedly]

But from this screen I think it was started successfully:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04.2 running screen]

I have tried many solutions but none of them work for me:

1. [Enable RemoteFX](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/hyper-v-new-vm-doesnt-start.49758/)
2. [Disable enhanced session mode](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-client-hyper-v-enchanced-session-keeps/adb7ba2b-9662-46d3-8397-bda905aa69f0)

I try to start all Hyper-V related services but only the following ones can be started: `HV Host Service`, `Host Computer Service`, `Virtual Machine Management`.

[image: The running Hyper-v related services]

I also find this error showing up when connection failed in `Event Viewer` > `Hyper-V-VMMS log`:

```
*The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service encountered an unexpected error: Unspecified error (0x80004005).*
```

Comment: Check if all HyperV related services are running in Service Manager (services.msc)?

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my description.

Comment: Personally, if I see any error having "unexpected error" message in Windows 10, I just clean install it.

Comment: Ok I will uninstall Hyper-V and install it. Hopefully the issue will be solved. Thanks.

Comment: No luck. Still getting the same error. I start to wonder if this is something to do with my hardware/drivers? maybe it's my network or video card? or 4K resolution?

Comment: This failed to make any difference for me. I ended up using VMware Workstation Player.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the exact same problem. For now I solved by disabling the enhanced session mode in the Hyper-V configuration. But different from you I disabled in the USER section and not in the SERVER section and works for me. 
I hope this can help

Comment: Here are further instructions on how to disable:  https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/57136-turn-off-hyper-v-enhanced-session-mode-windows-10-a.html

Comment: This failed to make any difference for me. I ended up using VMware Workstation Player.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I could use the machine with the enhanced session mode turned off, but this gives the limited usability.

The problem was that I set up the Ubuntu machine to log me in automatically. When I set it up to "Require password", I can use the enhanced mode.

Comment: Auto login was the problem for me as well

Comment: This failed to make any difference for me. I ended up using VMware Workstation Player.

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced session mode can allow dynamic resolution and better user experience but you must disable the auto login when connecting in enhanced session mode.

You can login via the basic mode first:
- select "view" from the toolbar
- uncheck the "Enhanced session"

Now, you should be able to login in its default solution. You can go to setting -> account and disable the auto login.

Comment: This failed to make any difference for me. I ended up using VMware Workstation Player.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on a Windows 11 VM which worked fine previously. No auto-login function.
I've tried disabling the Enhanced Session Mode in both the User and Server sections of the Hyper-V Settings but neither of these has made any difference. I've also checked the Hyper-V services and all seem to be running as expected.
I've also tried a fresh VM and tried to install Win 11 again but am having the same problem.

EDIT (27/02/2022): I have found a workaround for the Hyper-V problem by using a more reliable product: VMware Workstation Player. I've installed Windows 11 using [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-windows-11-vmware) article. It details how to bypass the TPM check which usually prevents Windows 11 from being installed in Workstation.